# CTE into a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I WANT TO CREATE A FUNCTION THAT MUST CONTAIN A CTE.

CTE works very well. The concern is that I can't intrude into the function.
My CTE allows to list configurations in a date range

I would like to know how to put the link between the CTE and the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ftliste_NameId
    (@dateStart DATETIME, 
     @dateEnd DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
    RETURN
        (WITH List AS 
         (
              SELECT DISTINCT 
                  CASE 
                     WHEN RG.Name IS NULL 
                        THEN R1.Id 
                        ELSE NULL 
                     END as Id,
                     RG.name  
                 FROM
                     dbo.fttable_table2(@dateStart, @dateEnd) R1
                 LEFT JOIN
                     (SELECT Name 
                      FROM dbo.fttable_table2(@dateStart, @dateEnd)
                      GROUP BY Name
                      HAVING COUNT(Name) > 5) AS RG ON R1.Name = RG.Name
         )
         SELECT *
         FROM dbo.fttable_table1 RD 
         JOIN List RL ON RD.Id = RL.Id

         UNION ALL 

         SELECT *
         FROM dbo.fttable_table1 RD  
         JOIN List RL ON RD.name = RL.Name 
         GROUP BY RD.Name
```

Errors in syntax

> Message : In each view, the names of columns or functions must be unique. Column name 'Id' is specified multiple times in view or function dbo.listNameId

Comment: You forgot to post the error you're getting. :)

Comment: Also, you you don't pass parameters to a table, why do you have syntax like `FROM        dbo.table2(@dateStart, @dateEnd) R1`?

Comment: In each view, the names of columns or functions must be unique. Column name 'Id' is specified multiple times in view or function dbo.listNameId

Comment: Larnu it's just an example for the name of my function the real name dbo.ftListe_listeName

Comment: Guessing `dbo.table1()` (that still makes no sense) has a column called `ID`, as your CTE, (`LIST`) also has a column called `ID`. The error is literally telling you the problem.

Comment: Then don't confuse things by using syntax like `FROM dbo.Table1 (@dateStart, @dateEnd)` @HAMZA. At least name your objects what they are.

Comment: Never use `SELECT *` in anything that's permanent, it's a maintenance nightmare. Doubly so when you're selecting from multiple objects without disambiguating; you make it very easy for stuff to break just by adding a new column to a table, something you always want to be possible.

Comment: What is the solution? Larnu

Comment: Don't have 2 columns with the same alias, HAMZA . The error is still telling you the problem here (my opinion hasn't changed on that). If you get rid of the `*`, like @JeroenMostert suggests (which you should) you solve 2 problems at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The advice in the comments is good: specify the column names instead of `*`.

You also have a GROUP BY that doesn't make sense, so I'm trying to guess what you wanted:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ftliste_NameId
    (@dateStart DATETIME, 
     @dateEnd DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    WITH List AS 
     (
          SELECT DISTINCT 
              CASE 
                 WHEN RG.Name IS NULL 
                    THEN R1.Id 
                    ELSE NULL 
                 END as Id,
                 RG.name  
             FROM
                 dbo.fttable_table2(@dateStart, @dateEnd) R1
             LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT Name 
                  FROM dbo.fttable_table2(@dateStart, @dateEnd)
                  GROUP BY Name
                  HAVING COUNT(Name) > 5) AS RG ON R1.Name = RG.Name
     )
     SELECT RD.id, RD.name
     FROM dbo.fttable_table1 RD 
     JOIN List RL ON RD.Id = RL.Id

     UNION

     SELECT MIN(RD.id), RD.name
     FROM dbo.fttable_table1 RD  
     JOIN List RL ON RD.name = RL.Name 
     GROUP BY RD.Name
```